# Ruby Dir.foreach in System32 misses files / File.exists? returns false for existing files

Tags: ruby, windows, system32, rubypython

When I print out all files in the windows 7 system32 directory using ruby, some files are missing. I use this simple directory iteration:

```rb
Dir.foreach("C:\\Windows\\System32") do |fname|
  puts fname
end
```

I am specifically looking for python27.dll, which is not printed, though it exists. File.exists? seems to have the same problem as the dir iteration. it returns false for an existing file:

```rb
File.exists? "C:\\Windows\\System32\\python27.dll" #returns false
```

Checking for another existing file of the folder works:

```rb
File.exists? "C:\\Windows\\System32\\quartz.dll" #returns true
```

But it does not work if I duplicate an existing file or create a new one in system32

```rb
File.exists? "C:\\Windows\\System32\\quartz2.dll" #returns false
```

Also, copying python27.dll to another directory and checking for existence works:

```rb
File.exists? "C:\\Otherfolder\\python27.dll" #returns true
```

The problem has nothing to do with letter-case or the path delimiter. I checked that. Also, I don't see differences in the user-rights for files that work and that don't ...

I really have no idea, why this happens ... can anyone reproduce this???

thanks

**[edit]**

Took a while, but I found the answer.

It was a 32/64-bit issue. for ruby as a 32bit application, "C:\Windows\System32" is actually "C:\Windows\SysWOW64". As the 64bit WinExplorer showed, python27.dll was in System32 (which only 64bit processes see - well, confusing), wheras it should have been in SysWOW64 for ruby to see. Installing the 32bit version of Python fixed the problem for me (as I couldn't change the ruby script, because it was part of rubypython).

Comment: I don't think it's the problem, but I prefer to use `/` instead \ or the masked \\, even when I work with windows. `/` works fine and with \ I got problems. There is also `File::SEPARATOR` and you can build pathes with `File.join`.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 7 (Vista, actually), a lot of security policies that existed only on paper in earlier versions of Windows, are now actually enforced by the operating system. For example, according to Microsoft's documentation, it has been pretty much illegal to write to `C:\Windows\System32` for decades now, but if you actually tried it, it still worked. Not anymore. As of Vista, `C:\Windows\System32` is off-limits.

However, in order not to break existing (broken) applications, Microsoft introduced filesystem virtualization. If an application tries to write to `C:\Windows\System32`, it gets silently redirected to `C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Windows\System32`. So, this specific application sees all the files it created or changed in `C:\Windows\System32`, but *other* applications see only the unchanged / empty directory.

This does not just apply to `C:\Windows\System32` but also to other system directories as well. Also, it applies to system parts of the registry, like `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` for example.

This virtualization is per-application. I.e. if Application A tries to create or modify a file in a protected directory, Windows will intercept that call and redirect it to the VirtualStore. It will also record this redirection somewhere. Now, when that same application A tries to look there again, Windows will use the recorded redirection, so that the application *thinks* the file is where it put it, when in fact, it is somewhere else entirely.

However, if a *different* Application B looks at that directory, then the redirection is not triggered and B just sees a pristine system directory. This is the whole point: in the past, different applications would create all sorts of weird bugs by overwriting each other's files in system directories. I.e. one application would dump its `python27.dll` into `C:\Windows\System32` and another application would dump *its* own, slightly different incompatible version of `python27.dll`, overwriting the first one.

So, you used *one* application to copy the DLL there (probably `explorer.exe`) and you use a *different* application, namely `ruby.exe` to look at it. But `explorer.exe` didnt't *actually* copy it into `system32`, it got redirected to the VirtualStore. When you use `explorer.exe`, the redirection gets triggered and you see the file right where you *think* you put it, but when you use `ruby.exe`, the redirection does *not* get triggered and it sees the directory as it actually is.

I *bet* that

```
File.exists? "C:/Users/#{ENV['Username']}/AppData/Local/VirtualStore/Windows/System32/python27.dll"
```

returns `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Valuable information and a good guess. The actual problem was a 32/64-bit issue though.

Comment: @CodeSalad: Yeah, that's basically the same thing but for a different purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the files are available in `C:\\Windows\\System32\\`?

I don't know this problem from the `System32`-folder, but I had some problems like yours with the `Program Files`-folder.

If you try to save data in some system folders and you are no Admin, Win7 don't store it at that location, but in a user specific Virtual Store. When you look at your system folder, files from the virtual store are also shown there. But the path is another one.

You may check your virtual store anywhere in `c:\users\<username>\Appdata\local\Virtual Store\` (at least the Program-folder is there).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Valuable information and a good guess. The actual problem was a 32/64-bit issue though.

Answer (score 0):

I've had same problem, it turned out that ruby can behave this way when working with paths longer than 260 symbols:

```
  Administrator@WIN-NUMKGBH6IIM ~
  $ mkdir -p /cygdrive/c/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/

  Administrator@WIN-NUMKGBH6IIM ~
  $ /cygdrive/c/opscode/chef/embedded/bin/ruby <<'EOF'
  puts File.exists?("C:/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/")
  EOF

  true

  Administrator@WIN-NUMKGBH6IIM ~
  $ /cygdrive/c/opscode/chef/embedded/bin/ruby <<'EOF'
  puts File.exists?("C:/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/123456789/")
  EOF

  false
```