# C++ reports file does not exist, even though it does

Tags: c++, windows, file

My Windows C++ program reports a file does not exist, even though it does.

I confirmed the file exists both with CMD and with Windows Explorer.

CMD test:

```
>dir C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity%4Trace.etl
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is DCCE-93FA

 Directory of C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs

03/22/2022  02:20 PM         1,048,576 Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity%4Trace.etl
               1 File(s)      1,048,576 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  1,571,579,912,192 bytes free
```

Windows Explorer test:

[image]

My C++ code:

```
std::ifstream file;
const char* path = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\winevt\\Logs\\Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity%4Trace.etl";
file.open(path);
if (file.is_open()) {
    std::wcout << path << " exists\n";
} else {
    std::wcout << "Failed to open " << path << "\n";
    perror("Error");
}
file.close();
```

C++ program's output:

```
Failed to open C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity%4Trace.etl
Error: No such file or directory
```

I ran my C++ program as Administrator, so there shouldn't be any permissions problem. (Plus, if there was a permissions problem, I would expect a different error message.)

I'm looking for any ideas of how to fix my program so it can open the file.

Comment: Are you sure there are no hidden characters in the file name?

Comment: `C:\WINDOWS\System32` is one of the paths which are "redirected" when running 32-bit processes on 64-bit Windows (the WOW64 layer).   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector

Comment: Expanding on Ben's comment, [sigcheck](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sigcheck) from Microsoft can tell you if an EXE is 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: @BenVoigt That was the problem. I was building my program as a 32-bit executable, not a 64-bit executable. Once I compiled it as a 64-bit executable, the file was found. If you convert your comment into an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: We don't really need another answer explaining it.  There's https://stackoverflow.com/a/66262831/103167 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26222532#comment41126618_26222532 https://stackoverflow.com/a/12122732/103167   https://stackoverflow.com/q/15603087/103167 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71252302#comment125946559_71252302 https://stackoverflow.com/q/37258855/103167

Comment: Then I think my question should be closed as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/66262735/8593689